# Why txt file created by jar doesn't work but creating from IDE it works?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a problem that I think is weird.
The structure it's easy, I create a file (.txt) from an app and then another apps use that file.

When I create a file from .jar, its size is 24kb but when I create the exactly file from IDE, its size is 27kb.
I was comparing the text but it is the same.

**The problem is the other apps cannot use the file (.txt) created by jar.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nVQX.png)

My code is:

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("../calendario_anual.txt")));
    writer.write(fechaSeleccionada + "\n");
    String patronSemanaPersonas = "___";
    String patronSepararPersonas = "_ñÑ";
    String patronPersonasHorario = "ñÑ_";
    String calendarioString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.calendarioRotaciones.size(); i++) {
        String keySemana = "Semana " + (i + 1);
        calendarioString += (keySemana + patronSemanaPersonas);
        for (int j = 0; j < this.ordenPersonas.length; j++) {
            // Semana
            if (j == 0) {
                calendarioString += (this.ordenPersonas[j] + patronPersonasHorario);
            } else {
                calendarioString += (patronSepararPersonas + this.ordenPersonas[j] + patronPersonasHorario);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < this.calendarioRotaciones.get(keySemana)
                    .get(this.ordenPersonas[j]).length; k++) {
                if (k == 0) {
                    calendarioString += (this.calendarioRotaciones.get(keySemana)
                            .get(this.ordenPersonas[j])[k]);
                } else {
                    calendarioString += (","
                            + this.calendarioRotaciones.get(keySemana).get(this.ordenPersonas[j])[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        calendarioString += "\n";
    }
    writer.write(calendarioString);
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If the files are different sizes then they definitely do not contain the same data, even if it looks similar. I notice that you do not specify the character set when you create the `FileWriter`. What charset do you think is being used, what charset do the text files actually use, and what charset(s) do the other apps accept?

Comment: Remember, when you do not explicitly choose a charset, unless you know for certain that the system default is correct and is what you desire, what you are saying is, "I do not care what character set this text is encoded in, and Shift JIS, KOI8-R, and EBCDIC are all equally acceptable to me."

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you, it works. I put the UTF-8 encoding and the output text file size was the same (.jar or IDE output).

`writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("../calendario_anual.txt"), "UTF-8"));`